LangSmith-OpenAI- "Inaccurate API key"
I've been using Langchain and Langsmith to create a benchmarking workflow for my LLM prompts.
Everything's been working well, until I had to delete are re-create my OpenAI API key.
I've updated the API key in the env.py as the main environmental variable, and this works- I've tested this with the OpenAI Chat Completion.
I've also updated the API key in LangSmith by going into the requested prompt's playground > Secrets & API keys > updated it manually. I even checked my under my organization's Settings > Secrets, and see the API key is updated.
However, when I try to use the "arun_on_dataset" function in the aforementioned Python environment, it gives me an error-
"AuthenticationError("Error code: 401 - {'error': {'message': 'Incorrect API key provided: sk-O6ZSB***************************************TNxS. You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys."

The prefix for the API key the error throws is indeed the previous, non-functional API key, but I don't know where else to adjust it so it'll read the current API key.
Nothing was changed in the code, which ran well previously, and the only external adjustment was the API key.
Should I change the API key elsewhere?
Any thoughts and ideas are welcome!
